# Looking for a blog engine to use with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blogs

I'm looking for a blog engine or a framework for implementing a simple blog in Java. The application should be deployable on the Google App Engine platform.

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1086465/246069

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/instant-press/

Comment: No, I'm looking for some engine or framework implemented in the Java language. The suggestions made in the answers to this question only lists python implementations.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/ihere-blog/ Have not tried it but seems promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely check out [vosao](http://www.vosao.org/). I'm using it some time and it's really great.

Answer (score 0):

Check out bloggart 
https://github.com/Arachnid/bloggart
And use it together with https://github.com/garethr/appengine-image-host
To upload photos for your blog post.

It gets very frequent updates contributors. I'm using it for my own website.
http://honcheng.com